# Issue with implementing custom Comparator for Priority Queue in Java

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

Please pardon my understanding towards priority Queue and Comparator in Java.
It seems ,I am able to implement basic comparator for Priority Queue based on some sort order.
But I am not able to come up with something for the below scenario :

```
1. Given a list of Files with name convention xx_yy_zz.dat .<br/>
2.xx,yy,zz can be from 00-50 <br/>
3.I need to process the files with xx=30 first,xx=35 second xx=40 third and then the rest.<br/>
```

Since I have limited knowledge with Priority Queue ,I tried to implement it which i was able to sort but only in asc or desc value of xx  which was not the requirement.
My approach was

> put the list of file names in priority Queue ,split the filename on regex "_"
> then compare the first index of split array using comparator based on it values but as expected i failed miserably since my requirement was something different

Please share some ideas/approach.

It seems sadly ,I am not able to come up with the a required comparator for my case .
Nevertheless thanking you in anticipation

Comment: How should "the rest" be sorted? Can it be in any order or does it have to be in a specific order?

Comment: Thank you for your time.there is no such rule for others as such .but to be safe  lexicographic ordering  is prefered .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `if` statements inside the `compare()` method to check if one string starts with `"30"` and the other does not. Then you know that this string must come before the other one. You run the following `if` statements like this on the first part of the filenames:

1. Are they the same?
2. Is the left one `30`?
3. Is the right one `30`?
4. Is the left one `35`?
5. Is the right one `35`?
6. Is the left one `40`?
7. Is the right one `40`?

The comparator might look like this:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    String[] splitA = a.split("_");
    String[] splitB = b.split("_");

    if (splitA[0].equals(splitB[0])) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (splitA[0].equals("30")) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (splitB[0].equals("30")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (splitA[0].equals("35")) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (splitB[0].equals("35")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (splitA[0].equals("40")) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (splitB[0].equals("40")) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the following test source code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
Arrays.sort(data, new SpecialComparator());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

You might get an output like this (depending on the `data` array):

```
[30_45_35.dat, 00_12_34.dat, 35_50_20.dat, 40_03_05.dat, 33_28_14.dat,
 30_16_31.dat, 20_29_23.dat, 24_41_29.dat, 30_49_18.dat, 40_12_13.dat]

[30_45_35.dat, 30_16_31.dat, 30_49_18.dat, 35_50_20.dat, 40_03_05.dat,
 40_12_13.dat, 00_12_34.dat, 33_28_14.dat, 20_29_23.dat, 24_41_29.dat]
```

*(new lines added for clarity)*

As you see you have the `30`s first, then the only `35` second, then the `40`s third and after that all the remaining stuff. You might want to use [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) on the strings in case the `compareTo` method would return `0` to get better "sub sorting" of strings, which would be equal based on this basic sorting above.

Comment: Thanks a lot.i am very new to comparator .it worked as expected .one doubt is that I tried to add the  data list to a priorty queue,apply same comparator ,n poll data from it  .the order is changed.it is due to more  sub string sorting ?.when I am calling poll, element should be removed n again remaning all heapified based on the same comparator  .so why is ressult using priority queue fetching different result(not lexicographic) in this case.

Comment: @ArchiacCoder The complete order might be different when you don't add the additional lexicographic sorting of equal elements. But the overall ordering should still be that the `30`s come first, then the `35`s, then the `40`s and then the remaining stuff.

Comment: Thanks for info ! noted !

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm not understand what exactly you need... but simply try this code and it sort me all strings if they has two digits on the begining

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        PriorityQueue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>((first, second) -> {
            return Integer.parseInt(first.substring(0, 2)) - Integer.parseInt(second.substring(0, 2));
            //and if you want to reverse order, simply add "-" like this:
            //return -(Integer.parseInt(first.substring(0, 2)) - Integer.parseInt(second.substring(0, 2)));
        });


        q.add("23lk");
        q.add("22lkjl");
        q.add("45ljl");

        for(String str : q) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

adn output

```
22lkjl
23lk
45ljl
```

If this not solution, please explain problem with more details, may be I or anybody else will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your time.now add to your list 10abv,50abc,100aac, where string can be anything. Now I want order of retrieval should be 50abc,100abc,10abc,45ljl,22lkjl,23lk.. this is what I want given the queue...where the string can be anything